# Get logged in username when using vmware

Tags: powershell

I can usually see who's logged in by running

`Get-WMIObject -class Win32_ComputerSystem -computername w00879 | select username`

However. There are a few people who log into a virtual OS or use Remote Desktop Connection to connect to a computer, so pulling info from the above command, or checking the registry on the system, return blank, since they never physically logged into the device. Is there any other way to get this information?

Comment: I am not sure that I actually understand your environment but you can look in the "C:\Users" folder to see if they have logged on but I don't know if that is what you are asking.

Comment: How are these users logged into the computer? It should not matter if the computer is a VM or not when running those commands.

Comment: They log in using either Remote Desktop Connection or VMWare software. Either of those two fail to update the location used to see who is logged in, it shows up blank. If they physically log into the device, the command shows accurate information.

Comment: Try [`Win32_LogonSession`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394189(v=vs.85).aspx), but you'll need to filter based on LogonType.  Win32_ComputerSystem is the user who's logged on to the console.  You have to work your way back through Win32_LoggedOnUser to get the actual logon name, too.

Comment: [Here](http://poshcode.org/4304) is a function that appears to do it for you.

Comment: @BaconBits That's very involved indeed.

Comment: Yes, it is involved.  WMI/CIM often is. The issue is that Win32_LogonSession knows the type of logons involved (interactive, service, network, et al), but Win32_LoggedOnUser knows the mapping to Win32_Account where the name is.  You have to know both to know the account identity of who is actually logged on interactively.  You can use stuff like `Get-CimInstance Win32_LogonSession | Get-CimAssociatedInstance -Association Win32_LoggedOnUser`, but in my experience that often misses people, and doesn't work well run remotely.

Answer (score 0):

maybe go here http://psappdeploytoolkit.com/ and checkout the Get-LoggedOnUser function in AppDeployToolkitMain.ps1

It does exactly what you want.